# Scala.js js.Dynamic usage leads to a recursively infinite data structure

Tags: google-visualization, scala.js

I'm trying to use [Google Visualizations](https://developers.google.com/chart/) from [Scala.js](http://www.scala-js.org/). I generated the type definitions using [TS importer](https://github.com/sjrd/scala-js-ts-importer) and the relevant portion it generated is:

```
@js.native
trait ColumnChartOptions extends js.Object {
  var aggregationTarget: String = js.native
  var animation: TransitionAnimation = js.native
  var annotations: ChartAnnotations = js.native
  // ... more
}

@js.native
trait TransitionAnimation extends js.Object {
  var duration: Double = js.native
  var easing: String = js.native
  var startup: Boolean = js.native
}
```

Now, I'm trying to figure out how to actually use this and came up with:

```
val options = js.Dynamic.literal.asInstanceOf[ColumnChartOptions]
options.animation = js.Dynamic.literal.asInstanceOf[TransitionAnimation] // comment this and the next line and chart will appear
options.animation.duration = 2000
options.title = "Test Chart"
options.width = 400
options.height = 300
```

This works if I don't set the animation settings, but fails with the chart showing "Maximum call stack size exceeded" if I do.

I debugged, and found the following:
[image: animation contains a reference to itself]

So `animation` contains a reference to itself, but I don't feel like this should happen based on the code above.

Ideas how to fix it?

Any other suggestions on how to best use the generated types to provide a type-safe way of creating the JavaScript objects which Google Visualizations expects? I tried `new ColumnChartOptions {}` which looks cleaner than `js.Dynamic` but that failed with "A Scala.js-defined JS class cannot directly extend a native JS trait."

P.S. I'd like to note that

```
options.animation = js.Dynamic.literal(
  easing = "inAndOut",
  startup = true,
  duration = 2000
).asInstanceOf[TransitionAnimation]
```

actually works, but isn't type-safe (a mis-spelling of `duration` to `durration` won't be caught).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code lacks `()` when calling `literal()`, so the fix would be:

```
val options = js.Dynamic.literal().asInstanceOf[ColumnChartOptions]
options.animation = js.Dynamic.literal().asInstanceOf[TransitionAnimation] // comment this and the next line and chart will appear
```

In Scala (and therefore in Scala.js), the presence or absence of `()` is sometimes meaningful. `literal` is the singleton `object literal`, whereas `literal()` calls the method `apply()` of said object.

Comment: Thanks, this indeed helped.